# jest test of child component with this.var being passed fails as this is undefined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

attempting to test that the parent component simply contains a child component. all is good unless an attribute contains a THIS var, such as `name` in the code below:

Parent.js

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
handleChange(e){
  ...
}       

<Parent>
    <Child onChange={this.handleChange} /> 
</Parent>
```

Parent-test.js

```
...
container = shallow(<Parent />)
expect(container.contains(<Child onChange={this.handleChange} />)).toBe(true);
...
```

this will produces the following error message, indicating THIS is not defined:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

my goal is to do a test that shows the child component exists with the appropriate properties. i do NOT want to test the  component itself.

[edited to clarify the example]

Answer (score 1):

`this` is not defined in the context of the test that you are running. If you pass it as a `prop` when you create `Parent` for example, you can check for that value specifically in your test.

Also your `Parent` component is initializing the name of `Child` to literally *this.name*, not using a variable. You should do something like `name={this.name}` if you want to assign the value in the variable.

You should probably consider using `props` instead of `this.name` as well.

Comment: @Mario_F, thanks so much for your input. you are right about the assignment, i inadvertently typed it as a string in the example above, i will fix it.  your answer also made me realize i had simplified the example too much, as it did not appropriately show the full nature of the 'this'. thanks again!